# my component for the agGrid in angular doesn't work properly

Tags: angular, typescript, components, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

i have a componente that i'm trying to load on the AgGrid using the statusBar, but it show like this [out of ag grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYwUX.png), i have other pages where import in the same way and it works, but i don't know what i'm missing.
Ts file:

```
frameworkComponents = {
    countStatusBarComponent: CountStatusBarComponent
  };
  statusBar = {
    statusPanels: [
      {
        statusPanel: 'countStatusBarComponent',
        align: 'left'
      }
    ]
  };
```

html file:

```
<ag-grid-angular *ngIf="filters" style="width: 100%; height: 729px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
        [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" 
        [controller]="reports" 
        [filters]="filters"
        [noresult]="'WF_ATTI_LEGALI.SINTESI.ASSOCIA_RAPPORTI.ELENCO.NESSUN_RAPPORTO' | translate"
        [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" 
        [statusBar]="statusBar">
        <ng-template columnTemplate colId="plus" #kebab let-data>
          <a (click)="!loading ? associaReport(data.id): ''" class="plus-button">
            <i *ngIf="data" nz-icon nzType="plus" nzTheme="outline"></i>
          </a>
        </ng-template>
      </ag-grid-angular>
```

i tried adding a component like
Ts file:

```
frameworkComponents = {
    countStatusBarComponent: CountStatusBarComponent
  };
  statusBar = {
    statusPanels: [
      {
        statusPanel: 'countStatusBarComponent',
        align: 'left'
      },
      {
        statusPanel: 'agTotalAndFilteredRowCountComponent',
        align: 'right'
      }
    ]
  };
```

and it show like this [test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQLDt.png)